# Dynamically assigning Tag property on WPF controls

Tags: c#, wpf, tags, wpf-controls

I have a set of dynamically generated WPF control. How can I assign the Tag property of these controls dynamically?
I created the controls like this:

```
        SchlEntities db = new SchlEntities();
        InitializeComponent();

        var controls = from stud in db.Students
                       orderby stud.GroupID
                       group stud by stud.GroupID into gr
                       select gr;
        foreach (var gr in controls)
        {
            CreateComboBox();                
        }

private void CreateComboBox()
    {
        ComboBox combox = new ComboBox();
        combox.Width = 280;
        combox.Height = 30;
        combox.Background = Brushes.LightBlue;
        combox.Margin = new Thickness(5);            
        stackpanel.Children.Add(combox);
    }
```

Comment: have you consider to let wpf create your controls and just use datatemplate and your objects as an itemssource of your container? btw why you need a tag control?

Comment: What exactly do you means with tags? The `Tag` property? And i'm wondering where these ComboBoxes get their items from.

Comment: I meant the Tag property. The item is also from the database

Comment: I don't quite understand. Can't you assign `combox.Tag = ...` or what? If you reply here, please add a @Clemens in your comment so that i get notified about your response.

Comment: @Clemens I want to use the Tag property to uniquely identify each combobox that gets generated dynamically. Could you please suggest a much easier/better way of doing that?

Comment: Then why don't you do so? Put anything into the Tag property that lets you identify the ComboBox.

Comment: @Clemens How do I do that at runtime?

Comment: @Clemens As I'm dynamically drawing the controls, I want to be "naming" them as well

Comment: Then why don't you call `combox.Tag = someName`, where someName is a string?

Comment: @Clemens if I do that, all the combox will have the same "someName"

Comment: Of course you would have to generate a unique name for each ComboBox. But that's programming basics and i will stop this discussion here. Ask another question if you don't know how to generate unique names or ids.